# yii cache dependency referrer

Tags: yii, expression, outputcache, referrer

I'm building a small webshop. This shop has categories and products. 1 product can have multiple categories.
At the productpage a breadcrumb-path shows the referring category-name (via urlReferrer).

Im trying to get Yii to cache by page with OutputCache, depending on the referrer (the category, since this would change the breadcrump-trail).

Here is my non-working filter:

```
public function filters() {

    return array(
        array(
            'COutputCache',
            'duration' => 3600,
            'varyByExpression' => array($this->getReferringCategory()),
            'varyByParam' => array('id','slug'),
            'dependency' => array(
                'class' => 'CDbCacheDependency',
                'sql' => 'SELECT MAX(date_updated) FROM product WHERE product_id = '.Yii::app()->request->getParam('id'),
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Does anybody have a good approach for this?

Best regards, thanks!

Comment: In which class do you have the `filters()` method?

Answer (score 0):

'varyByExpression' param should be a PHP expression (it would be evaluated by eval) or PHP callback (would be evaluated by call_user_func_array())

if you use php >=5.4.0, try something like this:

```
'varyByExpression' => function(){return $this->getReferringCategory();},
```

Or like this, for older versions:

```
'varyByExpression' => '$this->getReferringCategory()',
```